# Powershell - Remove entries from delimited list of times/dates, keeping only earliest or only latest entry of each date?

Tags: powershell, date, time

I have two large .csv files of chronologically sorted dates and times, delimited with commas, which is structured as follows:

```
27/07/2020,3:39:13 AM
27/07/2020,4:19:05 AM
27/07/2020,4:19:06 AM
27/07/2020,4:19:07 AM
31/07/2020,1:04:02 AM
31/07/2020,1:04:04 AM
6/08/2020,11:46:30 AM
6/08/2020,11:46:31 AM
6/08/2020,12:43:55 PM
6/08/2020,12:43:56 PM
```

In both files I need to reduce the entries to only one per date, keeping the first entry for each date in one file, and the last entry for each date in the other.

I've tried to use substrings and regex to parse the text and then Add-Content it into a new file, but I just can't get it right. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried

Comment: If you don't mind waiting a little bit (because `group-object` can be slow on large collections) there's always `get-content c:\path\to\file.csv |group {$_.split(',')[0]}|%{$_.group[0]}`, but it's super simple. Then for the last item of a given date just change the last bit to `$_.group[-1]`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

...because I'm a moron and @Olaf helps. Have the Mk-III solution.
Motivation behind the changes in the comments.

NEW (I hope correct) ANSWER:

Even more improved, thanks @Olaf

```
$Top = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$Bottom = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

# skip -Header parameter if the CSV has headers
$csv = Import-Csv $InputFile -Header date, time 

# Gets a list of the unique dates
$Dates = $csv | Select-Object date -Unique

# For each unique date
foreach ($data in $dates) {
    # on every objects where its Date property is equivalent to the looping date
    $temp = ${csv}.where({ $_.date -eq $data.date }) |
        # orders them by their Time property casted as [Datetime].
    # Sort-Object -Property @{e = { [datetime]::Parse($_.time) } } 
        
    # loads in the ArrayList the first item, which is the lowest==earliest time
    $top.insert(0, ($temp | Select-Object -First 1))
    # loads in the ArrayList the last item, which is the highest==latest time
    $bottom.insert(0, ($temp | Select-Object -Last 1))

}

# add -NoHeader and\or -Append parameters as necessary
$top | Export-Csv $OutTopb
$bottom | Export-Csv $OutBottom
```

OLD WRONG ANSWER:

If it's a raw list\CSV without headers: `Get-Content $FileInput | Select-First 1 | Out-File $FileOutput`

If it's a CSV with headers: `Import-Csv $FileInput | Select-First 1 | Export-Csv $FileOutput`

Replace `Select-First` with `Select-Last` as needed. And of course `$FileInput` and `$FileOutput` can be the same

BONUS: you can pipe it to `Sort-Object` before `Select-First`\`Select-Last` should the values not being in order already

Comment: My bad, I did understand "date" as "whole date, including the time"

Uopdating the answer.

Comment: basically short-hands for `Select-Object -First\-Last`    

for each unique value of `date`, it sorts them by the `Time` property(being PM\AM it always sorts correctly) and then returns only the first or last object which is the earliest or latest time of each day.     

I suppose you can replace `Sort-Object -property Time` with `Sort-Object -Property @{e = { [datetime]::Parse($_.time) } } ` to make sure it's ordered by time correctly

Comment: @Olaf I managed to improve the solution quite a bit thanks to thinking how to answer you. Thanks.

Comment: *short-hands for Select-Object -First\-Last* ... if someone copies your code as it is it will fail.  ‍♂️  *it sorts them by the Time property(being PM\AM it always sorts correctly)* ... that's only the case for the given examples. If you have a time of `1:04:02 PM` and `5:25:00 AM` the result will be wrong with your current approach. Since you already mentioned a solution in your comments in your code why don't you make your solution more resilient? 

Comment: About the dates: Weird, everything worked in my tests. I must have not tested thoroughly enough. I do agree it was shortsighted of me not implement the more resilient solution as main answer.   

About `Select-First\\Last`: ...I have been using them so long I forgot they were cmdlets form PSScriptTools, lol. Going to update the answer